# Meaning of "slow-building"

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning, phrases

What does *slow-building* mean in that sentence? Does it mean "movements that were built slowly"?

> Some of our stories are about **slow-building movements** that display great momentum and dexterity in the use of nonviolent power but forsake short-term gains for long-term dreams. Other stories are about rapidly organized campaigns […].

More example sentences are given [here](http://www.wordnik.com/words/slow-building).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sentence is about social movements, associations of people with a common goal (probably political). A movement is *slow-building* if it starts with few people and little media recognition, and progressively becomes better known. The movement builds up slowly over time, as it gathers more participants and organizes more activities. *Slow-building* implies that the movement was built slowly, as a result of a sustained effort or a passive rise towards success, and that this building up is still ongoing.